# C#: Picture Box control not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a new desktop application in C# using Windows Forms.
In one of my form i put the `"Picture Box"` control which dynamically loads a new pic, each time when user performs a specific operation. The code for changing picture is as follow:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(PicURI);
```

The only problem which i face is that some time it displays a red cross rather than displaying proper image. I debug the application and find that `PicURI` contains the proper path of image as expected so i don't understand where does the problem lies?

Edit:
Change Code from

```
this.pictureBox1.Picture = Image.FromFile(PicURI);
```

to

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(PicURI);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really using `PictureBox`? it doesn't have [Picture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) property. If you really mean `PictureBox`, you could use `Image` property as suggested by `deepi`

**EDIT:**

Red Cross Indicates that an Exception has been thrown inside. Since `PictureBox` has handled the exception, you are not aware of that. However, you can set the VS to break when exception occurs(even though it is handled), by checking the CheckBox `Thrown` for a particular exception on `Debug -> Exceptions`

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(PicURI);
```

Answer (score 0):

He is using some user control with picture box in it. The Picture is public property in user control which return the image of pictureBox.

I think it display red cross because you had set the red cross image in user control's picture box. Some of the picture format are unreadable directly from Image.FromFile() and for that case it's showing same.